# Do Javascript objects allow keys that contain spaces?

Tags: javascript, object

**My Data:**  I have a an Array of Objects:

```
var totalsArray = [
  { Applications: 1, Computing Servers: 0, Contracts: 0, Country: "United States" },
  { Applications: 1, Computing Servers: 0, Contracts: 0, Country: "Italy" },
  { Applications: 1, Computing Servers: 0, Contracts: 0, Country: "United States" },
  { Applications: 1, Computing Servers: 0, Contracts: 0, Country: "Spain" }
];
```

**My Code:**  I then try to extract the keys using the following code:

```
var objectKeys = d3.keys(totalsArray[0]).filter(function(key) { return key;} );
```

However, I get an error because of the space in the key named "**Computing Servers**".

**My question:**  Is there a way to properly create and keep the "space" in the key name/string?

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: use["array notation"]

Comment: you need to stringify

Comment: IIRC: you will also need to put quotes around the property names as you are initializing the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, a propery name can be any string (all values are coerced to strings before they are used internally).

This can be done using quotes (double or single) around names in literals:

```
{ Applications: 1, "Computing Servers": 0, .. },
```

Just as it can be done with using the `obj[prop]` syntax (where `prop` is *any* expression that can be converted to a sensible string value):

```
obj["Computing Servers"] = 42;
```

Comment: This technique is also useful for reserved keywords like "if" or "function" or "continue".